# How would I use javascript to seperate a string with two cities (and their states) into their own variables?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to code a way for this string to be broken into two separate variables. The city name could be one or more words and the state will always follow the last word in the city's name.

```
var splitFlightInfo = "LOS ANGELES CA MIAMI FL"

var temp;
var theFlightInfo = splitFlightInfo.shift().split(" ");
var theflightDate = theFlightInfo.shift();
var theFlightArrive = theFlightInfo.pop();
var theFlightDepart = theFlightInfo.pop();
var theFlightPorts = splitFlightInfo.shift();

for(var p = 0; p < theFlightInfo.length; p++){
  if(p === 0){
    temp = theFlightInfo[p];
  } else{
    temp += ' '+theFlightInfo[p];
  }
}
```

Expected Results:

```
var departPort = "Los Angeles, CA"
var arrivePort = "Miami, FL"
```

Actual Results: none

Comment: `LOS ANGELES CA MIAMI FL` in this how you're deciding city name is only 3 word long ?

Comment: How do you treat string like `LOS ANGELES CA ST PAUL MN` (referring to [Sait Paul / St. Paul Minnesota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Paul,_Minnesota))? Or `LOS ANGELES CA EL PASO TX` (referring to [El Paso, Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Paso,_Texas))? There are also [cities with names that are only one or two letters long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_short_place_names), though, in fairness, there are no particularly large ones in the United States.

Comment: I think this would have to be based on substring with length 2, but in order to avoid detecting stuff like the "El" from El Paso, you'd probably need to create a whitelist of US states that you actually want to detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match these strings using

```
/.*?\b[A-Z]{2}\b/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XK3FlF/1).

**NOTE**: If you want to precisely match U.S. states you may replace `[A-Z]{2}` with `(?:AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)`:

```
/.*?\b(?:AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)\b/g
```

**Pattern details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars as few as possible
- `\b[A-Z]{2}\b` - a whole word consisting of two uppercase letters.

Then, add a comma before the last 1+ whitespaces + 1+ non-whitrespaces with `.replace(/\s+\S+$/, ',$&')`.

JS demo:

```js
var regex = /.*?\b[A-Z]{2}\b/g;
var str = "LOS ANGELES CA MIAMI FL";
var res = str.match(regex);
console.log(res[0].trim().replace(/\s+\S+$/, ',$&'));
console.log(res[1].trim().replace(/\s+\S+$/, ',$&'));
```